# Let $a, b$ and $m$ be integers, and $m \ge 2, \ ab ≡ [ (a \bmod m) * (b \bmod m) ] (\bmod m).$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm relatively new to this, I got no idea how to proceed at all. I'm just bad at this chapter :( 
$$
m\mid (ab- (a \bmod m \cdot  b \bmod m)).
$$
How do I proceed after that? Is this even the first step?

Comment: What do you want to prove?

Comment: I just need to prove that ab =  [ (a mod m) * (b mod m) ] (mod m)

Answer (score 0):

Since, by definition, $m$ divides $a-a\bmod m$ and $b-b\bmod m$, rewrite the expression as
\begin{align}
ab-a\bmod m\cdot b\bmod m&=(a-a\bmod m)b+a\bmod m\cdot b-a\bmod m\cdot b\bmod m\\
&=(a-a\bmod m)b+a\bmod m\cdot(b-b\bmod m)
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to this... I don't understand what does this even leads to... I'm looking at my textbook and still dumbfounded by the whole proving method... Someone even put this as duplicate and I don't see any correlation with the linked question

Comment: Look, in the last  lie the facot $a-a\bmod m$ is a multiple of $m$ (by definition), hence its product by $b$ is too. Similarly, $b-b\bmod m $ is a multiple of $m$, hence its product by $a\bmod m$. What can you say of the sum of two multiples of $m$?

Comment: that actually means u can already divisible by M! I hope im going on the right track!

Comment: What do you denote $u$?

Comment: the whole equation is divisible by m. Sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Did you get it now?

Comment: yeap. Thank you for your help! Im really appreciate it!